# Memory stays high after deallocating UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage

I got UINavigationController inside my app with a rootVC "VC1", VC1 containts a collectionview with 2images inside every cell. When user select cell, navigationcontroller will pass images from cell to new vc "VC2" and then push it to the top of navigationcontroller. My problem is when I take down VC2 via popviewcontroller, VC2 is deallocated correctly but memory stays at the same higher level (after pushing new vc it increases from 60mb to 130mb). I've trying set image to nil, and imageview also but none of this work. Here's some of my code:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
 var selectedUserPollDetails : VC2?

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AppUserCell

    selectedUserPollDetails = VC2()

    selectedUserPollDetails?.leftPhoto = cell.leftImageNode.image
        selectedUserPollDetails?.rightPhoto = cell.rightImageNode.image
        navigationController?.pushViewController(selectedUserPollDetails !, animated: true)
}
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

lazy var arrow : ArrowBack = {
    let arrow = ArrowBack()
    return arrow
}()

weak var leftPhoto: UIImage?
weak var rightPhoto: UIImage?

 var leftPhotoImageview: UIImageView = {
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return imageview
}()

 var rightPhotoImageview: UIImageView = {
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    imageview.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageview
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
view.addSubview(leftPhotoImageview)
    view.addSubview(rightPhotoImageview)
  view.addSubview(arrow)
    arrow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleArrowBack), for: .touchUpInside)

}

func handleArrowBack(){
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    leftPhotoImageview.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    rightPhotoImageview.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)

    if leftPhoto != nil, rightPhoto != nil{
        leftPhotoImageview.image = leftPhoto
        rightPhotoImageview.image = rightPhoto
    }
}

deinit{
    leftPhoto = nil
    rightPhoto = nil
    leftPhotoImageview.image = nil
    rightPhotoImageview.image = nil
}
```

I've even added deinit at the end to make sure photos are deallocated. So basically when i'm trying to push VC2 again (after pop) amount of memory is doubled again (260mb) and so on... what causing this problem? what am i doing wrong?
btw. i've omitted less important func and vars

Answer (score 0):

You defo have a memory leak. I believe everytime
you push a new view via the nav controller it creates a brand new view i.e. the view is completely new and isn't reused. If you have strong references within the view you've pushed to they won't be released unless you deinit as they have a strong ref to view you've pushed so they linger around. You mentioned you deinit those items. Have you also tried marking leftPhotoImageView and rightPhotoImageView also as weak properties? Something is holding onto those images it would seem.

You could also change deinit to leftPhotoImageview = nil and rightPhotoImageView = nil rather than setting the imageview.image property to nil if that makes sense.

Comment: everytime when im casting imageview as weak or unowned there is a crash and the corrupted line is inside viewdidload 'view,addSubview(leftPhotoImageview!)' , so it seems that when im allocating VC2 imageview appeared to be nil, cuz ARC deletes reference to this imageview (?), but why on the init not deinit, do you maybe have any idea why is that happening? or any clue? besides i think i've tried everything that's why ended up here :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i found a solution, i don't know why i haven't trying this one, so i marked my imageview as lazy, and now memory is decreasing after popping vc